# Nativerscript tap area

Tags: nativescript

In my nativescript app I noticed that sometimes the tap does not trigger right a way.  I have to tap several times to trigger the event.  This happens on both, android and ios.

How can I increase the tap hot zone?  What else could be causing this to happen?

Thank you.

P.S.  I tried increasing the padding of the element whose tap event I am capturing, but that did not seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few factors at play here.

First, when you intercept a page-level event in NativeScript it seems to stop events from other widgets from firing. For example, if you tap on a text field but have a page-level listener for tap events, the tap on the TextField will be intercepted by the page-level listener.

Second, Double-tapping seems to exploit a timing issue in events, allowing the tap event to bubble up to the next listening widget.

Finally, when you have padding on the element you're trying to tap, the tap does not register on the padded areas. It will appear that you can only tap in the middle of the widget (inside of the padded area). In my case, the TextField on which I had padding had to be tapped directly in the vertical center (and that was with a padding of 5px).

To test it, try removing the padding from the element and see if the tapping works normally again.

I was able to create a very smooth / natural experience with the software keyboard by doing the following:

1. Wrap the TextField in a StackLayout and putting padding on the StackLayout instead of the widget
2. Add the page-level listener that dismisses the software keyboard ONLY when the textfield is tapped, and remove it once that listener is fired.

ex: XML file

```
<StackLayout id="loginFieldWrapper" padding="5 5 5 5">
    <TextView hint="Enter Login ID" id="loginField" keyboardType="number" returnKeyType="done" returnPress="{{hideKeyboard}}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Backing javascript file

```
   loginField.on(gestures.GestureTypes.tap, function(args) {
            page.on(gestures.GestureTypes.tap, function (args) {
                loginField.dismissSoftInput();
                page.off(gestures.GestureTypes.tap);
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I often increase the `height` and `width` of the view that have the tap event. You can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Dihn, let me give that a try.

Comment: Please be sure to report back if this works for you, I've been having a similar problem

Comment: The increase of dimensions did not help.  As I mentioned in my update.  I even tried increasing the padding of the view, no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the item inside some layout to increase the clickable area

```html
<StackLayout (tap)="select(param)">
      <Label text="{{description}}" textWrap="true" marginTop="40px" marginBottom="40px">
      </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: That's not a good idea for several reasons - firstly it slows the app down even more. NS is slow enough. If you have a StackLayout of Labels - putting each Label in it's own StackLayout is not a good idea. I'm using RadSidedrawer and it misses taps quite a bit - the problem should be solved at the NS level - maybe add padding to the hit-zone.

Comment: That would be great. Would you like to share an example/pointers of the same?